# SSIS package dependent objects on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, integration, database-administration

I need to create a localized environment for a SSIS package that would only have the objects and entities needed by tasks inside it.

It's a large & complex SSIS package and it connects to eight databases on the same sql server.

Is there a quick way to list all the tables, stored procedures, functions etc that will be utilized(directly or indirectly) when I execute this package.

Comment: The way I have done it in the past is: 1. Using `sys.objects` in the source database, get a list of every possible object; 2. Now go through that list and search through the package .dtsx file for each object. Despite people talking about lineage for many years now, there is no built in way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good thought by Nick, but even that will only get you objects that are used directly.   There is no quick easy way to get all the objects that will be used indirectly.